# PSTricks and LaTeX vs. pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, shell-escape

I'm trying to convert my thesis to `pdfLaTeX`, as `latex` + `dvips` behaves ugly when it comes to break (really long) URLs... I'm using up-to-date TeXLive 2012 on Linux.

The only problem is (so far), that I heavily used `pstricks` and the related packages and I am not able to get them working nicely on `pdfLaTeX` (see my pictures) when interacting between different `pspicture`-environments (also using this sometime to have text directly related to pictures underneath):

---

`latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf` (gs)

[image: latex]

---

`pdflatex` (arrow is missing)

[image: pdflatex]

---

Code for the example above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}   
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdf}{pstricks} %used for pdflatex
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-node,pst-func}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)
    \psTextFrame[ref=c,linestyle=none](-1.5,3)(1.5,4){First Plot}
    \psplot[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5]{-1.5}{1.5}{x 0 0.3 GAUSS}
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-1.5,0)(1.5,3)
    \pnode(1.5,0.5){A}
\end{pspicture}
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)
    \psTextFrame[ref=c,linestyle=none](-1.5,3)(1.5,4){Second Plot}
    \psplot[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5]{-1.5}{1.5}{x 0 0.6 GAUSS}
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-1.5,0)(1.5,3)
    \pnode(1.5,0.5){B}
    \nccurve{->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't realize `pstricks` works at all with `pdflatex`. I haven't used it, but have you considered `tikz`? If you have a lot of `pstricks` stuff, this might be too much work, but maybe it is possible to combine them? Like, use your plots, but create the arrow with `tikz`?

Comment: Have you thought about extracting the pstricks images to extra files, processing them with `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` an include them in your main document with `\includegraphics` (pdfLaTeX is able to handle PDF-images). With this you could reuse your `pstricks` work in other documents easily. With using e.g. Makefiles you could process everything automatically

Comment: @Anke: `pstricks` used in latex creates a pdf-file containing all pictures (one on each side), therefore the arrow *between* two pictures is lost... I have really many graphics (optical physics related thesis) and there are some graphics that have more that 50 lines of code...tried `tikz` at first, but some things were not possible / too difficult, so I decided to go the `pstricks`-way. @Stephan Lukasczyk: There are also passages where standard-text and pictures are directly connected. Will think about the Makefile, but I'm afraid that it will look bad, when including whole pages to keep it ok

Comment: @DL6ER Including graphics with the size of a complete page and passages of standard-text in between could be difficult, I agree. This will cause more trouble than you have by now… I can't imagine any solution for this, yet :(

Comment: @Stephan Lukasczyk: I agree. There might be no `pdflatex`-solution. Also `xelatex` is problematic, as it produces at least a hundred errors, which I began tracking... Maybe I will find myself working on a better solution for the `dvips`-driver. If I get it working, I will pass it to the corresponding package authors, so that the whole community might benefit from my work. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: With `latex` you have to use package `breakurl`, then long urls are no problem

Comment: @Herbert discussed that in a parallel question and managed to get a solution for the `latex` build-tree. So maybe I'll just continue using `latex` as I think it is difficult to use postscript depended tricks just where I want (also as text overlay).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several `pspicture`environments as paragraphs can be encapsulated by the `postscript` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}   
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdf}{pstricks} %used for pdflatex
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-node,pst-func}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)
    \psTextFrame[ref=c,linestyle=none](-1.5,3)(1.5,4){First Plot}
    \psplot[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5]{-1.5}{1.5}{x 0 0.3 GAUSS}
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-1.5,0)(1.5,3)
    \pnode(1.5,0.5){A}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)
    \psTextFrame[ref=c,linestyle=none](-1.5,3)(1.5,4){Second Plot}
    \psplot[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5]{-1.5}{1.5}{x 0 0.6 GAUSS}
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-1.5,0)(1.5,3)
    \pnode(1.5,0.5){B}
    \nccurve{->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{postscript}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

that will be handled as a single image. My `pdflatex` output:

[image]

Inside the `postscript` environment can be anything, except a pagebreak. It will always be handled as a graphic which is saved in `<file>-pics.pdf`, one page per image (if you have more environments).

Comment: This seems pretty interesting, thanks for your answer. As I solved my `latex`-related problem elsewhere, there is no need for this anymore. But maybe I will have to come back to your solution if I encounter a new problem later on.

Comment: @DL6ER: If you need `microtype` then you have to use `pdflatex` again I think because `microtype` will not work in `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

Comment: I think it will work well using: `\usepackage[DVIoutput=true]{microtype}\microtypesetup{protrusion=true,expansion=true}`

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1 (if you insist on using pdflatex)

When we use pdflatex to compile PSTricks code, the nodes must be in the same physical page of the auxiliary PDF file produced behind the scene.

Your original code makes the first figure and the second one get separated in different physical pages. Namely, the first one is on page `x` and the other one is on page `y` where `x=/=y`.

To make them on  the same physical page, we can put both in another `pspicture` as the container. See my code below for the details.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}   
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdf}{pstricks} %used for pdflatex
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-node,pst-func}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-4.25)(1.5,4.25)
\rput[b](0,0.25){%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)
    \psTextFrame[ref=c,linestyle=none](-1.5,3)(1.5,4){First Plot}
    \psplot[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5]{-1.5}{1.5}{x 0 0.3 GAUSS}
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-1.5,0)(1.5,3)
    \pnode(1.5,0.5){A}
\end{pspicture}}
%
\rput[t](0,-0.25){%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)
    \psTextFrame[ref=c,linestyle=none](-1.5,3)(1.5,4){Second Plot}
    \psplot[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5]{-1.5}{1.5}{x 0 0.6 GAUSS}
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-1.5,0)(1.5,3)
    \pnode(1.5,0.5){B}
    \nccurve{->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Method 2 (if you are happy to use xelatex)

Without modification in your original code, just compile it with `xelatex`. Done!

Comment: Thanks, this looks good and seems to be a considerable alternative to Herberts solution (as I can actually control *where* the two pictures will go). Using `xelatex` won't make me happy as I have the feeling that `xelatex` is running *much* longer than `pdflatex` oder even `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf`.

Comment: It will _not_ break my solution if you use the `postscript` environment in a correct way!

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: me too!

Comment: Thanks for your warning. This might really happen, so I will again think about `xelatex`, that will just be a match of timing. Just measured: `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf` = 15sec, `xelatex` just over 1min, also `xelatex` doesn't know the command `\pdffilemoddate` I am using to judge whether I need to run auxilary programms like `gnuplot` etc. again, or if I can save this time as the old pictures are still up-to-date.

Comment: Ok, in my opinion his solution is the better (more straight forward) one, so I accepted his answer right-away.

Comment: @DL6ER: Yes. His answer is much better than mine.